# nosetests.exe calling setup_class() but pycharm unit tests aren't

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, nose

I'm trying to port [SqlSoup](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlsoup/) to python 3. I'm using PyCharm as my IDE and I want to run the [unit tests](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlsoup/src/5b0cd0a5842f18f3bfce87a7ecc392516bac462f/tests/test_sqlsoup.py?at=default).

If I run the unit tests in pycharm I get the following output:

```
C:\bin\python\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.0.3\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" C:\Users\jdearing\Documents\deleteme\sqlsoup\tests\test_sqlsoup.py true
Testing started at 12:53 PM ...

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jdearing\Documents\deleteme\sqlsoup\tests\test_sqlsoup.py", line 25, in setUp
    engine.execute(sql)
NameError: name 'engine' is not defined
```

However, if I run the tests from the command line, everything works great:

```
C:\Users\jdearing\Documents\deleteme\sqlsoup>c:\bin\python\Scripts\nosetests-3.4.exe tests\test_sqlsoup.py
.............................
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 29 tests in 0.549s

OK
```

What is comes down to is that this method never gets called:

```
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        global engine
        engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
        for sql in _ddl:
            engine.execute(sql)
```

Yes, that's a global variable, I'll improve the unit tests after I get them running.

Pycharm asked me to install nose to satisfy the dependency, so I would assume its test runner is using that module and not a different one. Why is it giving different results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know for nose, the setup has to be the following format for nose to pickup and run at the start of the test class:

```
@classmethod 
def setUpClass(cls):
    global engine
    ...
```